# Juego de Mates Php

Tags: php

Tengo este código que hizo en su dia un programador,
este codigo lo que hace es que a través de otros php al seleccionar un juego selecciona el de mates. Lo que quiero hacer es hacer dos juegos más resta y multiplicación

```
<?php
session_start();
$host_name = "xxxx";
$database = 'xxxx';
$user_name = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database) or die     ("No se puede conectar a la base de datos");
if(isset($_SESSION['session'][2])) {

$usuario = $_SESSION['session'][2];
$guardar = "si";

}else{

$_SESSION['noregistrado'] = 'Invitado'.time();
$usuario = $_SESSION['noregistrado'];
$guardar = "no";
}


if(isset($_GET['acabado'])){

$respuesta2 = new \stdClass();
$respuesta2->final = $_SESSION['puntuacion'];
$respuesta2->usuario = $usuario;
$comprobar = "SELECT * FROM `USUARIOS` WHERE `usuario`='$usuario'";
$comprobar_q = mysqli_query($conexion,$comprobar) or die ("FALLA LA CONSULTA DE COMPROBACION");
$num = mysqli_num_rows($comprobar_q);
$puntuacion = $_SESSION['puntuacion'];

if($num==0){
    $query = "INSERT INTO `USUARIOS` VALUES ('$usuario','$puntuacion','SUMA 2 DIGITOS')";

}else{
    $query = "UPDATE `USUARIOS` SET `puntuacion1`='$puntuacion' WHERE `usuario`='$usuario'";
}

mysqli_query($conexion,$query) OR DIE ("FALLA LA CONSULTA DE INSERTAR");

$posicion = "SELECT `usuario`, `puntuacion1`, rank
FROM
(
  SELECT `usuario`, `puntuacion1`, @n := IF(@g = puntuacion1, @n, @n + 1) rank, @g := puntuacion1
FROM `USUARIOS`, (SELECT @n := 0) i
ORDER BY `puntuacion1` DESC) q WHERE `puntuacion1` = '$puntuacion'";

$pos = mysqli_query($conexion,$posicion);

$posi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pos);

$posic = $posi['rank'];

$respuesta2->posicion = $posic;
$respuesta2->guardado = $guardar;

if($guardar == 'no'){

    $borrar = "DELETE FROM `USUARIOS` WHERE `usuario`='$usuario'";
    mysqli_query($conexion,$borrar);
        }




echo json_encode($respuesta2);

}else {


if (isset($_GET['respuesta'])) {


        //TODO: comprobar tiempo
    $clires = $_GET['respuesta'];
        $respuesta = new \stdClass();

    if ($clires == $_SESSION['num1'] + $_SESSION['num2']) {

        $_SESSION['puntuacion']++;
        $respuesta->mal = 1;

    } else {

        $respuesta->mal = 0;
    }


    $resultado = $_SESSION['num1'] + $_SESSION['num2'];
    $respuesta->resultado = $resultado;

    $_SESSION['num1'] = rand(10, 99);
    $_SESSION['num2'] = rand(10, 99);

    $operacion = $_SESSION['num1'] . '+' . $_SESSION['num2'] . '=';

    $respuesta->operacion = $operacion;
    $respuesta->ok = 1;
    $respuesta->puntuacion = $_SESSION['puntuacion'];
    echo json_encode($respuesta);



} else {

    $_SESSION['puntuacion'] = 0;
    //$_SESSION['gameStart']= timestamp();
    $_SESSION['num1'] = rand(10, 99);
    $_SESSION['num2'] = rand(10, 99);
    $operacion = $_SESSION['num1'] . '+' . $_SESSION['num2'] . '=';
    $respuesta = new \stdClass();
    $respuesta->operacion = $operacion;
    $respuesta->ok = 1;
    echo json_encode($respuesta);


}


}
```

Como puedo hacer para que cuando seleccione el juego de restas con id X me salgan las operaciones correctas?

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita más información: haría faltan partes claves del código (p.e. el HTML para saber qué datos tienes y se pasan); además, realmente la pregunta no tiene ningún problema: es un programa que funciona y que quieres ampliar (casi parece que lo que quieres es que alguien haga trabajo nuevo para ti de forma gratuita). Deberías añadir lo que hayas intentado y los problemas con los que te estés encontrando, tal y como está redactada la pregunta, es demasiado amplia.

Answer (score 1):

La elección de nombres de variables (y valores) no es nada legible, por ejemplo, $respuesta->mal = 1 cuando la respuesta es correcta y $respuesta->mal = 0 cuando es incorrecta. O tal vez el código que falta no me permite entender lo que hace el programa. Lo que entiendo es:

La primera parte, hasta

```
echo json_encode($respuesta2);
```

lo que hace el programa es obtener los datos de puntuación y ranking del jugador. A partir de ahí viene el juego, y lo que hace es presentar una suma de dos números enteros aleatorios de dos dígitos. Cuando el usuario introduce los datos, comprueba la operación y si es correcta le suma 1 a la puntuación: `$_SESSION['puntuacion']++;`

Lo que no veo por ningún lado es que el usuario pueda seleccionar el juego de sumas, restas ni nada. Pero en fin, tienes dos opciones:
1.- Que cada juego esté en un html diferente con funciones diferentes
2.- Que exista un control donde el usuario pueda elegir el juego y según el valor introducido ejecute este código (de sumas) u otro (restas, multiplicación)

En ambos casos debes escribir las funciones que calculen la resta y la multiplicación, que básicamente es copiar eso que tienes ahí y cambiar los + de:
`if ($clires == $_SESSION['num1'] + $_SESSION['num2']) {` y de `$operacion = $_SESSION['num1'] . '+' . $_SESSION['num2'] . '=';` por - y *
Eso sí, si sólo haces eso habrá resultados negativos cuando num1 sea mayor que num2.

Un saludo